# How to retrieve 3D models from a server in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: 3d, unreal-4, unreal

How can I load 3D models from a server in Unreal Engine?

Comment: What have you tried based on your research so far?

Comment: @DMGregory I just found a solution https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/195214/import-pak-from-remote-server.html

now working on it

Comment: Want to share your solution as an Answer below? Be sure to include the detailed steps, not just a link.